# Call to a member function extension() on null when running php unit test

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-8

I doing a test on a function when a user uploads a resume. my controller is :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // allowed extension
    $allowedExtensions = ['pdf', 'doc'];
    // get uploaded resume extension
    $extension = $request->file('resume')->extension();
    //change uploaded filename to random name
    $randomGen = random_int(150, 268);
    $filename = $this->generate_string($randomGen) . '.' . $extension;

    // check extension of uploaded resume and proccess it
    foreach ($allowedExtensions as $ext) {
        if ($ext == $extension) {
            $path = $request->file('resume')->storeAs(
                'resumes', // path or folder name in aws s3 (created if no path exist)
                $filename, //filename
                's3' //server
            );

            $resume = Resume::create([
                'filename' => $filename,
                'url' => Storage::disk('s3')->url($path)
            ]);
            return $resume; //temporary return value until view is created
        }
    }

    return redirect('/resume')->with('status', 'Allowed file is : .pdf or .doc');
}
```

and my test is :

```
    /**@test */
public function test_resume_upload()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
    $resume = __DIR__ . '/stub/resume_test.pdf';
    // dd($resume);
    $response = $this->post('/resume', [
        'resume' => __DIR__ . '/stub/resume_test.pdf'
    ]);

    $this->assertCount(1, Resume::all());
}
```

when i run the test git gave me Error: Call to a member function extension() on null